# Request.QueryString doesn't work in vbscript Asp classic?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, request.querystring

I have one problem ... I try two days to get QueryString which contains characters which are URL encoded like this %8B%83%94%837n . All that characters are from here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm .

Now when I try to get the QueryString from %8B%83%94%837n I get only the last characters 7n. They are not some special characters which must be encoded. This is work in Asp classic vbscript.

Is anyone has solution for this I would be thankful if help me. Any other solution of this problem is acceptable.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear to me what the question is here. Do you want to convert the encoded string `%8B%83%94%837n` back to a regular string? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

MyVar = server.htmldecode(YourQueryString)

MyVar = server.htmlencode(YourQueryString)